# websocket sockJS connection on spring cloud gateway eurekaproblem

Tags: javascript, spring, websocket, cloud, gateway

I have microservice architecture which works on spring cloud API gateway with eureka instances as clients and i need some help with forwarding websocket connection

[image]

While connecting to websocket service directly through localhost on port 8085 everything is working:

```
const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8085/websocket');
```

When I try to connect through API gateway on localhost port 8083 there is a connection error:

```
const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8083/websocket');
```

API gateway routing :

[image]

I tried a lot of combination also

```
.uri("lb://messaging-service:8085"))
.uri("ws://messaging-service:8085"))
```

Websocket configuration :

[image]

[image]

Error:

[image]

Tried everything with allowing headers, some diffrent cases on websocket URL etc.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557